# Gelfand-Naimark for $C^*$-categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, operator-algebras

What is a reference for the following Theorem?

> If $A$ is a small [$C^*$-category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/C-star-category), then there is a faithful $C^*$-functor $A \to \mathsf{Hilb}$.

$C^*$-categories with exactly one object are just $C^*$-algebras, and in that case the Theorem coincides with the usual Gelfand-Naimark Theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Theorem 6.12 of Paul Mitchener's article *$C^\ast$-categories*.

Comment: Thank you! The article is here: http://www.mitchener.staff.shef.ac.uk/cstarcat.dvi